# Way to manually activate Bioshock on an offline PC?

Tags: pc, bioshock

Is there any way to manually activate Bioshock PC on an offline computer? Has anyone used the site Bioshockunlock.com to get an unlock code for an offline PC?

Thanks

Comment: Don't give your serial number to any external website such as this. Period.

Comment: Should we edit the question to not link there, especially if it's a phishing site?

Comment: It's legit, @McKay, @MrPanda. I changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: I already removed it, but I'll put it back up. I think that forum is where I got the link initially.

Answer (score 2):

<s>Who linked you to that website?</s>

The offline activation tool seems to suggest you email support@securom.com and I suggest you do that.

<s>The page you linked could very well be a scam.</s>

[The website seems legit](http://forums.2kgames.com/forums/showthread.php?t=20556&highlight=bioshockunlock), as it is referenced in a pinned thread by a moderator on the official 2kgames boards.

Comment: I wouldn't say that's enough evidence for it being legit... a moderator is not necessarily a company employee, and maybe he just found it online and provided link without checking it himself.

Comment: Really? On a two years old sticky with 3k views? Without other mods and admins checking on him?